# Can't access from SSH to secondary public IP

Tags: azure, ssh, ip, stun, turn

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 with two public IPs on Azure, one primary and one secondary in the same network interface. I need two public IPs to be able to mount a STUN / TURN / ICE server.  I can access the main one by SSH but the secondary one doesn't work. Should this be so? How do I fix it if it's an error? How do I know that server get traffic from secondary IP? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at your Network Security Group (NSG)?

Comment: I do not understand what you're referring to. The NSG is common for both and has the SSH port open, and in the rule I have not seen anything that refers to the IP. Sorry.

Comment: There is one thing I'm not clear. Do you mean you associate two public IPs to only one network interface?

Comment: Yes, I have two public IPs in one network interface

Answer (score 0):

Solved following Microsoft's response:

[Can't access from SSH to secondary public IP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b0bf877-8064-49a6-9b65-dddeda72a81e/cant-access-from-ssh-to-secondary-public-ip?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork&prof=required)

Thanks you